# Unicode problem with JSF and HTML forms?

Tags: java, html, unicode, jsf

I have an HTML form generated by JSF which maps an input element to a bean setter
and it looks to me like JSF is garbling unicode input on the way in.  In particular I put the following exception for testing purposes in the setter

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    System.out.println("title set with: "+title+"\n");
    if (title.startsWith("xxx")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("debug exception "+title);
    }
    this.title = title;
}
```

Then I put the following text into the form title input element: "xxxx 海陆". Then when I submit the form I see the log print

```
title set with: xxxx ?????
```

(on a unicode compatible mac terminal).
And I get an error message on the response HTML page:

```
Error setting property 'title' in bean of type   
uk.ac.lancs.e_science.sakaiproject.api.blogger.post.Post: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: debug exception xxxx ���??
```

Any clues on what's wrong?  Am I just full of it and have the wrong diagnosis?
I think I've eliminated all other possibilities.  Unicode seems to work fine in other components of the same application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions I would be asking:

- How is the form encoding the request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data)? Multi-part data will be decoded using a 3rd party MIME parser, so there is scope for trouble there. If the data is url-encoded, is it being escaped properly?
- What charsets is the browser [accepting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers)?
- What [encoding is the server detecting](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestCharacterEncoding())? Is it a Unicode character set?
- Is it just the logging that is writing as a [lossy encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_lossyconversions) (e.g. [MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroman))? What [default charset](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()) is the server using?

Since what you see on a console isn't necessarily what is in the string, you can dump the [Unicode code points](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) using this code:

```
  public static void printCodepoints(char[] s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      int codePoint = Character.isHighSurrogate(s[i]) ? Character
          .toCodePoint(s[i], s[++i])
          : s[i];
      System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(codePoint));
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's a multipart form.  Maybe I'll try switching to url-encoding. thx.

Comment: HEY! This appears to work!  Just change to standard post encoding.  Thanks

Comment: I would not be so quick to celebrate. I've seen multipart/form-data used to _overcome_ character bugs and it is required if you want to do form file upload. Still, at least you have an idea about where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

A browser can't send unicode over the wire; it has to encode the unicode in some way. From the output of the exception (two kanji became five characters), I'm guessing the data was encoded as UTF-8 and the string `title` wasn't decoded correctly after reception in the server side of the component.

I suggest to set the `accept-charset` attribute for the form. That should tell everyone to behave.

Comment: Your guess is my guess too.  I need to use utf-8 (my educational application may include chinese and sanskrit in the same input element).  I'm not sure how setting accept-charset on the client side form will make the server side component decode utf-8 correctly.  How does that work?  Anyhow, what is the syntax exactly?  I'll give it a try...

Comment: A form post/get is actually a HTML request. With accept-charset, you tell the browser which charset the server expects. The browser will also put this information into a header field of the request so your framework will see it. That way, everyone involved will get a hint what to do.